# Cannot manage to use LoginStudentNumber as my login id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to use my *LoginStudentNumber* as a login id, but every time I try login in, it doesn't recognize the *LoginStudentNumber* .
However the login page works when I use the *LoginID* attribue as the login id.
This is my login table:

```
LoginID(Pk)      LoginStudentNumber      LoginPassword
    1                 123456                 1234
    2                 234567                 2345
    3                 345678                 3456
```

I can't seem to understand why it recognizes *LoginID* but not *LoginStudentNumber*.

I tried fiddling with this line of code in particular (in my controller):

```
RMS.Models.Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginID);
```

Here is the rest of my code:

Login Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RMS.DAL;
using RMS.Models;

namespace RMS.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        RMSContext db = new RMSContext();


        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(Login model, int? LoginID, string LoginPassword)
        {


            RMS.Models.Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginID);


            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid User Id");

                return View(model);
            }



            if (user.LoginPassword.Equals(LoginPassword))
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password");
            return View(model);

        }
    }
}
```

Login View:

```
@model RMS.Models.Login

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->

    <link href="~/Content/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles -->

    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="background-color:white">
    <img src="~/img/thrupps.png" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0px 490px 0px 490px; " />
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="login-wrap">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form" }))
            {
                <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag.Name1
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginStudentNumber, "LoginStudentNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginID, "LoginID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag.Name2
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginPassword, "LoginPassword", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block " value="Login" />

                @Html.ValidationSummary()

            }
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RMS.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public string LoginStudentNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Note: The code above works for me only because I am using LoginID as my login id. Any suggestions on how I can use `LoginStudentNumber` as my login id.

Comment: Your question isn't clear?!

Comment: my apolagies. I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace your Code in your Login with this:

```
 RMS.Models.Login user = db.Logins.SingleOrDefault(t => t.LoginStudentNumber == model.LoginStudentNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

EF method [find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) takes primary key for the entity as a parameter and you want to find it by login. You can use [FirsOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb918914%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method:

```
...
RMS.Models.Login user = db.Logins.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LoginStudentNumber == model.LoginStudentNumber );
```